# Django showing: OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'

Tags: python, django

After I restarted my PC the terminal showed ImportError as follows

```
ImportError: Couldn't import Django. Are you sure it's installed and available on your PYTHONPATH environment variable? Did you forget to activate a virtual environment?
```

So  i install django. But when i run the command to start the server i got this error.

Following some suggestions i have tried

- force-reinstalling django
- Making migrations

Still hte error persist, i dont know the cause of this error please help me out.

```
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 932, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper  
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 76, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in 
execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 53, in wrapper  
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 91, in populate    
    app_config = AppConfig.create(entry)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 90, in create        
    module = import_module(entry)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1014, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 991, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 973, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'allauth'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 401, in 
execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 395, in 
execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 328, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 60, in execute
    super().execute(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 369, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 95, in handle
    self.run(**options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\runserver.py", line 102, in run
    autoreload.run_with_reloader(self.inner_run, **options)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 599, in run_with_reloader
    start_django(reloader, main_func, *args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 584, in start_django
    reloader.run(django_main_thread)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 299, in run
    self.run_loop()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 305, in run_loop
    next(ticker)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 345, in tick    
    for filepath, mtime in self.snapshot_files():
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 361, in snapshot_files
    for file in self.watched_files():
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 260, in watched_files
    yield from iter_all_python_module_files()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 105, in iter_all_python_module_files
    return iter_modules_and_files(modules, frozenset(_error_files))
  File "C:\Python38\lib\site-packages\django\utils\autoreload.py", line 141, in iter_modules_and_files
    resolved_path = path.resolve(strict=True).absolute()
  File "C:\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 1174, in resolve
    s = self._flavour.resolve(self, strict=strict)
  File "C:\Python38\lib\pathlib.py", line 200, in resolve
    return self._ext_to_normal(_getfinalpathname(s))
OSError: [WinError 123] The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect: '<frozen importlib._bootstrap>'
```

Comment: you have to install django all auth

Comment: yaa right I didn't notice that, thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

I also faced the same issue, the reason in my case was I missed one ',' in between the apps names in the **INSTALLED_APPS** section of `settings.py`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'data.apps.DataConfig',
    'circulation.apps.InfoConfig',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'info'
    'data',
]
```

missed comma in between 'info' and 'data'

Answer (score 0):

I have face this issue when there is a package named django-bootstrap3==14.1.0 along with Django ==3.1

** I did pip install django==2.1.15 which solved my issue,
To conclude compatibility between the  is one of the reason**

note: in command line I faced this while after installation of Django 2.1.15
"ERROR: django-bootstrap3 14.1.0 has requirement django<4.0,>=2.2, but you'll have django 2.1.15 which is incompatible."

Answer (score 0):

if you have a installed app on setting file bun not in the venv directory you have this error for solve that you should be ins